# How to lock files correctly in ANSI C

Tags: c, file, locking

I am writing an ANSI C cgi-bin server program.
Each instance of program can access to the same files simultaneously.
I do as follows:

```
handle = fopen(name,type);
fd = fileno(handle);
MyLockFile(fd)  //I use fcntl
.....
```

The problem is that I open file with "fopen", not with "open".
Will "locking" work in such manner?
I can lock "fd", not "handle".

The reason is that I can't write workable "fd=open..." code.
My code below creates the executable file, write permissions were not set.
I don't know why

```
fd = open(name,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|S_IREAD|S_IWRITE|S_IRGRP|
     S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);
write(fd,data,strlen(data));
close(fd);
```

I can neither write nor append to this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your open() function is wrong, when you specify O_CREAT, the permission bits needs to be the 3. argument, e.g.

```
 open(name,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 
      S_IREAD|S_IWRITE|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);
```

Comment: Oh yes!!!! Thanks! But is it possible to open with "fopen" and then "fd=fileno(handle)" and then lock fd?

Comment: @nms Well, the fcntl docs says "Because of the buffering performed by the stdio(3) library, the use of record locking with routines in that package should be avoided; use read(2) and write(2) instead.
"

Comment: As I understand "fopen" is a routine on low level "open", and we should use low level "open","write","read" for locking instead of "fwrite,... Okay. Understood. Thank you!!!

Comment: @nms: There is nothing wrong with using a system level function like open(), instead of the standard library function fopen(), but that would be defined in POSIX.  It would be greater than the plain ISO/ANSI C standard.